# Why IE11 executes unsuitable media queries randomly?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, media-queries

I've a bad display of my web site randomly on IE11 because it executes the media query for width less than 767px whereas the windows's width is more than 767px. This problem occurs randomly however, it never occurs when the debug window is open.

I'm using Twitter Boostrap v2.3.1.

This is one of the rules executed causing the bad display of the web page :

```css
@media all and (max-width:767px)
[class*='span'], [class*='span'].uneditable-input, .row-fluid [class*='span'] {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Should your snippet not be:

```
@media all and (max-width:767px) {
    [class*='span'], [class*='span'].uneditable-input, .row-fluid [class*='span'] {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
}
```

Try that. It looks as though you mixed your media query rule with your selectors.